# Is there a way to backup and restore basic file / folder permissions on Ubuntu the way that there is using icacls in Windows?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, backup

In Windows you can do [this](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/viewing-saving-and-restoring-ntfs-permissions/) (backup and restore basic file permissions) can this be done in Linux?

And to clarify, by basic file permissions I don't mean ACLs in Linux, I mean the default permissions modified with `chmod` / `chown`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the `stat` command (See `man stat`, `man find`, `man xargs`), but why would it be needed? In normal Linux life, wholesale permission changes/restores are rarely needed.

```
sudo find / \(-type f -o -type d \) -print0 | \  
    xargs -0 stat <stat parameters>
```

Comment: You'd need it if you were changing permissions on some of the files in a directory of many files and aren't sure if the permissions are going to be set correctly for something you are testing out.  It would allow you to revert to the original permissions if you get it wrong when testing it.

Comment: That seems like the Windows Method. The Linux(Unix) way is to understand permissions (`man 2 chmod`) and ACLs (`man -k acl`), understand what you want to do before making wholesale changes. A script like my `pathlld`[link](http://pastebin.com/rFGm9cqc)script could help

Answer (score 0):

If you have the space, just `tar` up your test directory. If you need to revert things, delete the test files, and extract your archive to get back to what you started with. `tar` preserves ownership and permissions by default.